# Time information in elasticsearch data

Tags: python, elasticsearch, kibana

I am sending data to elastic-search from a python script , it works fine and i am able to view it in Kibana. Now i want to insert the timestamps for each record/document so that i can get some plot in Kibana , based on the time information , for example , the number of documents submitted per five minutes , etc.

When i append the time information to each record , it is visible in Kibana as simple data , and further more , the time field is not there when viewing from elastic search HQ mapping section. What could be the problem? In what format should i insert the time stamp , and do i need some special field name for it ? ( I am using Kibana3 , the filed name i am using is '_timestamp')

Comment: You could use logstash to pipe data from python to elasticsearch. Personally doing that currently, and I have a recent record with the format `2016-02-18T22:38:27.568Z`, for example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure the field is mapped as a date field in ES and not a text field, that is likely your issue.

The field name doesn't matter, other than when you tell kibana about your index make sure you pick the correct field.

The ISO/XML datetime format is the default for ES, but it can be changed in the mapping if you needed it to be.
`2016-02-18T22:38:27.568Z`